# Moving button doesn't receive click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text field which should hide when it loses focus. I also have a button. The problem is, when you click the button, the text field first loses focus, which moves the button, preventing it from receiving the click event.

HTML:

```
<div>
   <p> Focus on the text field, and then click the button </p>

   <div id="hideMeOnFocusOut">
        <input type="text" id="focusMeOut" autofocus>
       <br><br><br>
  </div>
  <button id="clickMe">click me</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('#focusMeOut').on('focusout', function(e) {
    $('#hideMeOnFocusOut').hide();
  });

  $('#clickMe').on('click', function(e) {
    alert('clicked!');
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u86ycf5e/

The button should still move. But it should also receive the click event.

Answer (score 0):

Add a container with a height around the element you are hiding: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/u86ycf5e/1/)

```
.container {
    height: 50px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="hideMeOnFocusOut">
        <input type="text" id="focusMeOut" autofocus>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could make the element hide after a short delay via `setTimeout` like so:

```
$('#focusMeOut').on('focusout', function (e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#hideMeOnFocusOut').hide();
    }, 250);
});
```

[Other fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/u86ycf5e/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
  $('#focusMeOut').on('focusout', function(e) {
    $('#hideMeOnFocusOut').hide();
      if (e.relatedTarget.id==="clickMe") {
          $("#clickMe").trigger('click');
      }
  });
```

This will check to see if the button was clicked and fire it ...

Answer (score 0):

Hide the text box instead with:

```
$('#focusMeOut').on('focusout', function(e) {
  $(this).hide(); //this line changed
});
```

and optionally set the height of the `<div>` to prevent button moving with this CSS:

```
#hideMeOnFocusOut {
    height:80px;
}
```

You might want to rename your IDs more appropriately now.

http://jsfiddle.net/u86ycf5e/4/